# How to capture intellitrace event log for a web application which is already running?

Tags: intellitrace

I'm using a web application which uses a many dlls. The debugging happens by attaching the aspnet_ws process to Visual Studio. I want to explore the intellitrace feature of VS 2010 and capture the event log. But when i try to attach the process to VS 2010 i'm getting a message in the intellitrace window that this feature could not be used for an already running process. If so is there any work around to achieve this? Please let me know if anyone has an alternate.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

IntelliTrace for Visual Studio 2010 does not support attaching to a process and collecting data.

Answer (score 0):

IntelliTrace has to launch the process in question itself. You can use Visual Studio's internally hosted web server to debug locally. I'm not certain, but you may be able to do historical debugging in IIS if you load a web project via URL in Visual Studio and start debugging.